# Reading a value from the command line with a .com file

Tags: assembly

Can I have a simple example of an assembly code that when compiled into a .com file (with TASM) will be able to read a value between 0 and 255 from the command line and place it into a register?

Ex: Test.com 255
(I should see FF in the register).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the command line by looking at the Program Segment Prefix; see http://www.fysnet.net/cmndline.htm for the details of where it is.  You will need to parse the number yourself, though.

Answer (score 0):

using a [dos interrupt](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html) you have to get that number and convert it manually to hex. if this sounds too complicated you can have a look at the [ucr standard library](http://webster.cs.ucr.edu/AsmTools/MASM/stdlib/stdlibv1.html), which contains basic functions such as conversion ones.